# Javascript code about mathematical factorials

Tags: javascript, math

I'm reading this book on JavaScript which has an exercise about calculating mathematical factorials. Well, it is presented in a playful way in which the code has to print out a word, (in this case "clunk") and the times it gets printed out depends on a number that is passed as an argument when calling a function.

In this example the number is 5, so you can make a total of 120 combinations (5x4x3x2x1).

The thing is I'm having difficulty understanding the logic in the code. Here it is:

```
function clunk(times) {
    var num = times;
    while (num > 0) {
        display("clunk");
        num = num - 1;
    }
}

function thingamajig(size) {
    var facky = 1;
    clunkCounter = 0;

    if (size === 0) {
        display("clank");

    } else if (size === 1) {
        display("thunk");

    } else {
        while (size > 1) {
            facky = facky * size;
            size = size - 1;
        }
        clunk(facky);
    }
}

function display(output) {
    console.log(output);
    clunkCounter = clunkCounter + 1;
}

var clunkCounter = 0;
thingamajig(5);
console.log(clunkCounter);
```

My understanding after reading the code was that the word "clunk", gets printed 5 times, then 4, then 3, 2 and 1, for a total of 15 times, because I thought each pass through the loop was added, not multiplied. 
I fail to see in the code why the first loop is to be multiplied by the second loop and so on until it reaches 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it stands, the code *will* print `clunk` 120 times.  The function `clunk()` will print the word `clunk` a number of times equal to its first parameter.  The `else` clause of `thingamajig` calculates the factorial of your provided number thusly:

```
while (size > 1) {
    facky = facky * size;
    size = size - 1;
}
```

Unrolled using your input of 5, that will be executed as:

```
facky = 1;
size = 5;

facky = facky * 5;  // Now facky = 5
size = 5 - 1;       // Now size = 4

facky = facky * 4;  // Now facky = 20
size = 4 - 1;       // Now size = 3

facky = facky * 3;  // Now facky = 60
size = 3 - 1;       // Now size = 2

facky = facky * 2;  // Now facky = 120
size = 2 - 1;       // Now size = 1, we stop our while loop
```

It then calls `clunk(facky)` which has a value of `120`, giving us the current output.

---

If it were to print 15 times -- using the logic you provided -- the `else` clause of `thingamajig` would looks like this instead:

```
} else {
    while (size >= 1) {
        clunk(size);
        size = size - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mr Llama. Yes, the code indeed will print out clunk 120 times. I knew that. My problem was that I didn't completely understand why. But you cleared it out for me. I thought "facky" always had a value of 1. Didn't realize it changed with each loop. First 1, then 5, then 20...etc. Think I got it now, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest running the code, preferably with a debugger. You will see that "clunk" gets displayed 120 times. Note that the function `clunk` only get called once, it is outside the loop.

So the loop calculates `facky` (1*5*4*3*2 = 120) and then the loop exits. Calling the function `clunk` once with a parameter of 120.